# c# Linq duplicates initialising of member

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query two tables and need to pull related records from both the tables. I am using enityframeworkcore 3 One is system versioned table and the other is history table. My resultset is containing data only from history table 
and not system-versioned table. Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my statement . I am ensured that the personid in the systemversion table matches the history table.

If I try to add the following to the select list I am getting duplicates initialising of member

```
select new PersonNote
          {
          AuthorId = pn.AuthorId,
          Created = pn.Created,
          Note = pn.Note,
          AuthorName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
          AuthorId = pnh.AuthorId,
          Created = pnh.Created,
          Note = pnh.Note,
          AuthorName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
```

Original query

```
public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
        {
        var personNotes = (from pn in _context.PersonNotes
                   join pnh in _context.PersonNotesHistory on pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId
                   join p in _context.Person on pn.PersonId equals p.Id
                   select new PersonNote
                   {
                         AuthorId = pn.AuthorId,
                         Created = pn.Created,
                         Note = pn.Note,
                         AuthorName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                   }
         );
   return personNotes;
   }
```

Data

[image]

Comment: Your code tries to specify two values for each of the properties - an object initializer can only specify each property once. Which values do you want - the ones from `pn` or the ones from `pnh`?

Comment: Pls provide example data, if you have multiple rows in PersonNotesHistory you will get multiple rows in result

Comment: Hi Jon, I need data from both the tables. System versioned tables in sql are way of time tracking the data modified. So the current data resides in the system versioned table and historical data in the history table. I need to pull the historical data as well the most recent data for that record which sits in the system versioned table

Comment: Ihave updated the post on how data looks like

Answer (score 0):

Change the table order for joins. Start from Person, join it with PersonNotes on personId, and then with PersonNotesHistory (pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId).

```
public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
    {
        var personNotes = (from p in _context.Person
                           join pn in _context.PersonNotes on pn.PersonId equals p.Id
                           join pnh in _context.PersonNotesHistory on pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId
                           select new PersonNote
                           {
                               AuthorId = pn.AuthorId,
                               Created = pn.Created,
                               Note = pn.Note,
                               AuthorName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                           }
                           );
        return personNotes;
    }
```

This projection wont give you the data from pnh because nothing is selected.

Comment: This query doesnt even compile for me. Getting error types of arguments cannot be inferred from the query. I need data from both the tables